# Is there a way in f# to perform a cross operation on lists?

Tags: f#

Is there a way in f# to perform an opreation on the all the possible element combinations of two lists in f#?

Example

```
l1 = [1;2;3]

l2=[4;5;6]

let plus x y = x+y
```

Then fun plus l1 l2 would perform `[(1+4);(1+5);(1+6);(2+4);(2+5);(2+6);(3+4);(3+5);(3+6)]`

Hence the output: `[5;6;7;6;7;8;7;8;9]`

Note: I have tried using zip but it only takes each element once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, easiest way is to use a list comprehension.

```
let t1 = [1;2;3]
let t2 = [4;5;6]

[for a in t1 do for b in t2 do yield a+b] //val it : int list = [5; 6; 7; 6; 7; 8; 7; 8; 9]

//as a function
let f lst1 lst2 = [for a in lst1 do for b in lst2 do yield a+b]
```

Comment: I changed `yield! [a+b]` to just `yield a + b` (because you do not need to generate singleton lists).

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to combine a List.collect with a List.map:

```
let l1 = [1;2;3]
let l2 = [4;5;6]

l1 |> List.collect (fun x -> List.map ((+) x) l2) //output: [5; 6; 7; 6; 7; 8; 7; 8; 9]
```